# L^p bounds for function on double annulus

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, estimation

The problem is
Consider the open disc $B_r=B(0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $\phi=\max\{|x|-1,0\}$ is the distance from $B_1$.
For $u\in C^1(\overline{B_3-B_1})$. Show that $\exists$ $c$ such that
(i)$1\leq p<+\infty$,
\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(B_3-\overline{B_1})}\leq c\left(\lVert \phi\nabla u\rVert_{L^p(B_3-\overline{B_1})}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(B_3-\overline{B_2})}\right)
\end{equation}
(ii)$1\leq p<2$,
\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{L^{p^{*}}(B_3-\overline{B_1})}\leq c\left(\lVert \phi\nabla u\rVert_{L^p(B_3-\overline{B_1})}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(B_3-\overline{B_2})}\right)
\end{equation}
Here $p^{*}$ is dual of $p$ satisfying $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{p^{*}}=1$.
Maybe the result can be shown for general compact sets $K\subset L$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any directions?